How to prove that $\mathbb{A}^2-pt$ and $\mathbb{A}^2-pt-pt$ are not isomorphic?
Let's fix an algebraic closed field $k$, and work in the category of schemes over $k$.
Let $U$ be $\mathbb{A}^2$ minus a (closed) point, and $V$ be $\mathbb{A}^2$ minus two (distinct closed) points. My goal is to show that $U,V$ are not isomorphic.
Firstly, $U,V$ are both non-affine, non-proper, and smooth.
I tried to calculate the cohomology of structure sheaf: their $H^0$ are both $\Gamma(\mathbb{A}^2,\mathcal{O})$ by algebraic Hartogs lemma. Let $V=\mathbb{A}^2-\{x,y\}$, then $V$ is intersection of $U_1=\mathbb{A}^2-\{x\}$ and $U_2=\mathbb{A}^2-\{y\}$, which are both isomorphic to $U$. By MV sequence, we have:

$H^i(\mathbb{A}^2)\to H^i(U)\oplus H^i(U)\to H^i(V)\to H^{i+1}(\mathbb{A}^2)$ is exact.

By explicit calculation via Cech cohomology, $H^1(U)$ is a countable dimensional vector space over $k$, hence $H^1(V)\cong H^1(U)\oplus H^1(U)\cong H^1(U)$. Also we have $H^i(U)=H^i(V)=0$ for $i\geq2$.
Therefore Zariski cohomology of structure sheaf of $U,V$ are the same.
If $k$ is of characteristic $p>0$, then the etale cohomology of constant sheaf $\mathbb{F}_l$ of $U,V$ seem to be different. But I think there's some problem in characteristic $0$.
And I also want to consider the generalized question, about isomorphic type of $\mathbb{A}^n$ minus $m$ points (this seems to have more than 1 isomorphic classes, though).

Consider the canonical morphism
$$
X \to \mathrm{Spec}(H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)).
$$
In both cases the map is an open embedding into $\mathbb{A}^2$, but the complement of the image is one point or two points, respectively. This shows that the two schemes are not isomorphic.
